# Create 256 color palette video

Tags: ffmpeg

I already have this working by converting the source video to GIF with:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 5 source.mp4 -vf fps=10,scale=480:-1,smartblur=ls=-0.5,crop=iw:ih-2:0:0 -hide_banner -loglevel panic output.gif
```

And then converting the GIF to MP4, like so:

```
ffmpeg -y animated.gif -hide_banner -pix_fmt yuvj420p -loglevel panic -an -loglevel panic final.mp4
```

What I want is to convert `source.mp4` directly to `final.mp4`, and have the same 256 color palette as a normal GIF.

I tried merging both commands together, and although it generates a MP4, the result is a 16 bit video, surprisingly smaller than a 8 bit video.

Do I need to generate a palette first with `palettegen` and then re-encode the video with this palette?

Comment: Yes, use palettegen and then paletteuse

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks. If you post this as answer, I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the palettegen and paletteuse filters, like is normally done for GIF creation.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -vf palettegen palette.png
```

and then,

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex "paletteuse" -c:a copy out.mp4
```